# помогите решить проблему laravel 8 ошибка таблица не найдена

Tags: laravel

Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'reviews.posts' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `name` = Александр Булкин

Создал форму при нажатии на btn submit эта ошибка

Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;


class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function nVSa(){
        return view('nVSa');
    }

    public function reviews(Request $request){
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|unique:posts|min:4|max:100',
            'email' => 'required',
            'msg' => 'required|min:15|max:500'
            ]);

            $reviews = new Reviews();
            $reviews ->name = $request->input('name');
            $reviews ->email = $request->input('email');
            $reviews ->msg = $request->input('msg');

            $reviews->save();
    }

}
```

Reviews.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reviews extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

2021_05_17_051122_create_reviews_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateReviewsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->text('msg');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('reviews');
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sueCs.png скрин бд

Comment: У вас таблицы posts нет в валидаторе правило уникью `|unique:posts|` после двоеточия надо указывать таблицу по которой проводить проверку на уникальность

Comment: Вам как бы сама ошибка говорит что в db reviews нет таблицы posts

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reviews extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: Нет таблицы а не полей

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Окау=))) Сама ошибка нам говорит об отсутствии таблицы которая используется в sql запросе а не полей, а проперти guarded с пустым массивом говорит что мы можем отправлять на запись любые поля а не только те что в филабл(насколько я понмю)